# Understanding hex opcodes

Tags: assembly, intel

Hello I have the following x86-Assembly:

```
 8048062:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
 8048064:   89 d8                   mov    eax,ebx
 8048066:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
 804806B:   cd 80                   int    0x80
```

I want to understand the hex-opcodes.
I read [here](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html) that `b8` and `89` are mov-instructions.
But I don't understand the second part of `89 d8` what is `d8`?
Is `d8` eax and ebx? So d is eax and 8 is ebx?
But why is in line one eax and `eax == c0`?
And where is in line three in `b8 01 00 00 00` the register?

And why is the following line correct?

```
8048066:    b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
```

why not:

```
b8 00 00 00 01 ?
```

eax is split into:

```
eax 32bit
ax 16 bit
ah 8bit
al 4bit
```

so why is `b8 01 00 00 00`  correct and not `b8 00 00 00 01`? cause of the "Little Endian"?

When i use `"mov al, 0x1"` the  hex-opcode will be just: `b8 01`
thats correct. I am a little bit confused at the moment.

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Download the x86 manuals from Intel's site. A comprehensive answer to these questions would be far too broad for a SO post.

Comment: _"why is `b8 01 00 00 00` correct and not `b8 00 00 00 01`?"_ Because x86 processors are little-endian, and the little-endian representation of the 32-bit value 1 is `01 00 00 00`.

Comment: thx for your reply michael. So I guessed right. But why is such a difference between the opcode parameters? @500-InternalServerError I've read it but I didn't understand it. Must be this SIB/MODRM thing :S

Comment: @Shibumi: "Must be this SIB/MODRM thing" - exactly.

Comment: By the way, both `ah` and `al` are 8bit, and don't overlap (they're the high byte and low byte respectively of `ax`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is d8 eax and ebx?

Yes.

> So d is eax and 8 is ebx?

No. It's more complicated, as you can see on [sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm](http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm.htm)

```
d8 = 11 011 000
     11         = both operands are registers
        011     = the 'r' operand is ebx
            000 = the 'rm' operand is eax
```

`mov r32, imm32` works differently, the destination register is the low 3 bits of the opcode, here `000` so `eax`. In the manual, that type of encoding is written as a + sign after the opcode, as in `B8+rd id`.

This is all explained in the manual, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the description I am looking for

Comment: Christ that site is an eyesore, with no explanations whatsoever. Why has no one made a more accessible website yet?